# setOnEditorActionListener not working with soft keyboard submit button, but does with laptop Enter key?

Tags: android

Can someone please provide a solution to get a working listener for the soft-keyboard `DONE` button, and/or explain what I'm doing wrong in my current approach?

My Xml & Java Setup

- In Xml, there's a simple EditText is set with `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
- In Java, it just has a basic `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` declared

So `setOnEditorActionListener()` is not getting called when there is a click from device soft-keyboard submit (aka `DONE`) button - the green arrow button below ; *only the EditText field is cleared*

[image]

But that listener DOES get called when clicking the computer `Enter` key *(attached via ADB)*.

I would figure it should work for both those buttons .. is this not right?

**XML Layout File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.demo.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        />    
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Activity File:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_text)).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int i = 5; // added this to set a break point
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> **Update for Solution**
>
> Thanks to @Apoorv Mehrotra's answer, it turns out that my EditText was missing this one attribute in order for the soft keyboard event to be recognized.  Adding this to the above Xml solves the problem.
>
> `android:inputType="text"`

Comment: That solved my problem as well as I had `                android:inputType="textMultiLine"` but the problem with `text` is that after I press enter the keyboard is hidden while with `textMultiLine` after pressing enter message is sent but the keyboard stays in focus

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution in a contextual sense. Any idea why the input needs to be declared for a key listener to be put in place?

Comment: Clearly non-logical that this is mandatory, this is a bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code this is a code with 2 fields in which i have user time feature. in first one keyboard shows next button and in second one soft keypad shows done option and on done option i hide the soft keypad.

below is the xml file code.

```
  <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="visible"
                />
```

now below is the java code: for hiding soft keypad on next and same can be performed for done option as well.

this code add in onCreate() of your class.

```
    EditText first_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    EditText second_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);

    first_txt.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                return true; // Focus will do whatever you put in the logic.
            }
            return false;  // Focus will change according to the actionId
        }
    });

second_txt.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                return true; // Focus will do whatever you put in the logic.
            }
            return false;  // Focus will change according to the actionId
        }
    });
```

This code works for , hope it helps you out!

Comment: With your answer, I was able to determine it was just 1 attribute that was missing from my code.  Please see update in original post for details.    Thanks for your quick reply and helping me find the solution, I really appreciate it *(I spent a few hours trying to solve for this one)*

Comment: I'll be glad to mark your reply as the accepted answer.  However - to have that status, I think the XML should be trimmed down to just what's essential for the solution, minus any unnecessary attributes - so it's easier for others to identify what the solution is.  Since your answer describes the xml that's there now, I figured it would be better if I didn't try to edit that.  Fyi - I created my demo project with just the EditText `"@+id/txt2"` - it has the solution for my post, matching the same `imeOptions=actionDone` setup that I have.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok .. well, I'll go ahead and mark it now so you can get the reputation.  The answer is certainly there. Maybe at your convenience you can trim it down some to make it easier for others to read through (I always look for the short answers first :) ).   Happy New Year

Comment: Thanks once again & Happy New Year to you too !

Comment: ok i will surely trim my code to whats needed exactly as soon as possible.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, for me, adding `android:singleLine="true"` in EditText did the trick

Comment: Wow this took a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue that seems not to be solved yet. There's a workaround for these cases. Simply take the EditText (or whatever View you might be needing this and assign it a onEditorActionListener, like this:

```
final EditText editor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editor.setOnEditorActionListener(EnterOnText);
```

Now define the EnterOnText implementation like this:

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener EnterOnText = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
      final String msg = view.getText().toString();
      if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
        // Do whatever you need here
        ...
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

Now, simply change the layout's imeOptions attribute to:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

That will, oppositely, probably make your emulator's enter key not work, but will (should) do on all physical devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_text)).setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //do something
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_text)).setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event != null && (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO
                            || event.getKeyCode() == event.KEYCODE_ENTER))
    {
    //do whatever you want
    }

                }
            });



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/comment_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    />
```

Comment: If you check for event being null, you will ignore soft input IME_ACTIONs.