# setOnEditorActionListener is not returning anything

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

It took me awhile to figure out this setOnEditorActionListener is the culprit. At least around that area.
Running the test on a real device won't trigger anything when enter is pressed.

Same thing with the emulator, but it works fine using Enter on my computer keyboard.
I have added some lines to my .xml file that was suggested from users here.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    mFilters = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ic_search);
    mSearchText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_search);
    Log.d(TAG, "getElasticSearchPassword: retrieving elasticsearch aissa password."+ mElasticSearchPassword);
    getElasticSearchPassword();
    init();

    return view;
}

private void init(){

mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new  
TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    ||actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                mPosts = new ArrayList<Post>();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                baseUrl(BASE_URL)

            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

            Code goes here
          }
          Return False
           }
         });
         }
```

Here is my original XML file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
    android:background="@drawable/grey_border_bottom"
    android:padding="2dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="search..."
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ic_search"
            android:id="@+id/input_search"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/ic_search"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_toolbar"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey">


  </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:visibility="gone">

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I tried to remove the if condition. Suspecting that some API don't respond to IME_ACTION.

Comment: EditText is AndroidManifest.XML? Please share `layout.fragment_search` xml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setOnEditorActionListener not working with soft keyboard submit button, but does with laptop Enter key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422954/setoneditoractionlistener-not-working-with-soft-keyboard-submit-button-but-does)

Comment: @FaysalAhmed you can see that I have added that solution to my xml, but the issue is still there

Comment: I have tried this and its working fine.