# setOnEditorActionListener not working for Android Pie(9.0)

Tags: android

I've tried a **setOnEditorActionListener** and it **works for** my Samsung **(Android version 7.0)** device. But it **doesn't work for** my Xiaomi AndroidOne **(Android version 9.0)** device. How can I fix this?

**Java Code**

```
mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute our method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**XML Code**

```
       <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_magnify"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/input_search"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked with
`android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attribute *android:singleLine="true"* to the edittext worked for me as suggested here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53468182/5853160 you can find more info about this property here -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:singleLine

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_search_members"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_search_icon"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="搜索分组/姓名"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true"></EditText>


 et_search_members.setOnEditorActionListener(OnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        if (actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            sendSearchData()
        }
        false
    })
```